# Structure and pointers arithmetic

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
  int roll_no;
  int total_marks;
} s1;

int main()
{
  struct student *stu;
  stu = &s1;
  printf("Address of member roll_no accessed by s1 = %u", &s1.roll_no);
  printf("Address of member total_marks accessed by s1 = %u", &s1.total_marks);
  printf("Value of stu = %u", stu); // which is address of s1.roll_no
```

Likewise, how do I get the address of `s1.total_marks` using stu?

Figured it completely.
Lets just say we have structure like this:
Every single one those members can be accessed in the following way,

````
   #include <stddef.h>   

   struct student    
   {   
      int roll_no;   
      char name[50];   
      double mark;   
      double percetage;   
   };   

   int main()   
   {   
   struct student s = {1, "Jug", 98.99, 97.5678};   
    
       printf("%d %s\n", *(int*)((char*)&s + offsetof(struct student,    
   roll_no)), (char*)((char*)&s + offsetof(struct student, name)));      
       printf("%lf %lf", *(double*)((char*)&s + offsetof(struct student,  
  mark)), *(double*)((char*)&s + offsetof(struct student, percentage)));        
   }```
````

Comment: Use `(void *)&(stu->total_marks)` and change format specification from `%u` to `%p`.

Comment: Thank you it gives the expected answer but the logic doesnt seems to fit. My understanding for ur response: &(stu->total_marks) It just goes to the address of the s1.total_marks for (stu->total_marks) for the '&' printing  the positions addr; what actually needed is as the value from the next members address i.e roll_no addr in stu present at memory location say like 2000-2003 accessed by using print(stu) likewise how do we get to 2004 -2007 for total_marks. Thank u so much for ur time.

Answer (score 2):

*Member access* operators (`.`, `->`) have higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the *address-of* operator (`&`). So `&p->m` is *not* equivalent to `(&p)->m`, but rather to `&(p->m)`.

Hence, you can use

```
&stu->total_marks
```

as well as you already wrote

```
&s1.total_marks
```

Answer (score 1):

As `stu` is a pointer to `s1`, just do:

```
&(stu->total_marks)
```